# How would you translate "insured for your peace of mind"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase, phrase-request

I am currently translating a flyer for my dad's renovation and property maintenance business from English to German (he recently moved to Germany). I am pretty confident with most of what I've done so far but I am still struggling with the phrase "insured for your peace of mind". I am thinking of something along the lines of "Wir sind fuer Ihr beruhigtes Gewissen versichert" but since I haven't spoken German for a long time I am not sure whether this sounds OK or how to phrase it better... Perhaps there is a standard German phrase for this kind of thing?

Suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Und was bedeutet "insured for your peace of mind"? Was ist der ganze Satz, was ist der Kontext?

Comment: Do you mean, your dad's business is insured against liabilities? That's not something you should bring to notice to German customers as they expect it anyways. They will instead understand the quality is subpar and he needs that insurance very often.

Comment: Pls, for the [sake of your](https://de.nachrichten.yahoo.com/knapp-daneben-lustige-%C3%BCbersetzungsfehler-140648068/photo-dieses-glas-mit-asiatischen-spezialit%C3%A4ten-1471529984166.html) [dad's business](https://www.twigg.de/wissenwertes/witzige-uebersetzungen/): You should get other people (native speakers) to look over your translation and double check it first, Even when you are pretty confident what you've done so far.

Comment: @Janka, thanks, I think that is good advice. I emigrated from Germany many years ago — had forgotten about the precise German mentality.

Comment: @mtwde :D — thanks, it’ll be checked by native speakers living there currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Janka points out, insurance is common and expected in Germany. Meaning there is not only no common phrase for that, but that it will even make people rather suspicious why you stress that than grab their attention in a positive way.

However, in case you have extraordinarily good insurance, or handle sensitive goods, for example expensive pianos, you could think about something along these lines:

> Umfassend versichert, damit Sie Unwägbarkeiten sorglos entgegen sehen können
>
> Solide versichert, damit Sie nachts ruhig schlafen können
>
> Solide versichert, für sorgenfreie Projekte
>
> Rundum sorglos versichert

I'd advice against *ruhigen Gewissens* because it has that connotation of "morally unquestionable", which is not what you mean.

Comment: 'I'd advice against ruhigen Gewissens because it has that connotation of "morally unquestionable"' - something like "ruhigen Gewissens" or "guten Gewissens" *might* work if using the service is some kind of "due diligence". For instance, someone assigned to clear your sidewalk from snow, if necessary, lets you leave for your vacation "giten Gewissens".

Comment: Thanks, that’s very useful. I will probably go with the suggestion of omitting it altogether, but nonetheless your translations are spot-on!